# How to open a folder with it selected?

Tags: c#, wpf

I download and use `CommonOpenFileDialog` from NuGet to open the folder selection window.
Since the functions are generally similar, you can think of using `OpenFileDialog`.

I saved the path of the folder that opened last in a text file and loaded it at the next run to run the folder selection window through `CommonOpenFileDialog.Initial Directory`.

It works well so far, but what I want to is that from the moment the folder selection window opens, the folder is already selected.

Since I have to check before opening the folder, it is possible to implement it right away without a folder selection window through the path, but it is an unwanted way.

I would appreciate it if you could give me advice.
I upload a part of the code I wrote for reference.

Thank you.

```cs
string readTexts = null;

if (fi.Exists)
   readTexts = File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName);

folder_dialog.InitialDirectory = readTexts;

if (folder_dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
{
    OpenTextBox.Text = selected_path = folder_dialog.FileName;
    WritePath(fi, System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(selected_path));
}
```

Comment: This issue seems better adressed by reading the documentation of the library you are using.

Comment: @Flater I tried it first before I posted, but I couldn't find the answer, so I posted a question just in case. As you said, I think it will be difficult to get an answer because it is a question about a specific API.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about `CommonOpenFileDialog` of WindowsAPICodePack, why don't you set the folder path to `DefaultFileName` property?

Comment: @emoacht It is correct to use CommonOpenFileDialog of WindowsAPICodePack.
Before using CommonOpenFileDialog, the code implemented at the time of using OpenFileDialog is reused.
And I don't know what the DefaultDirectory property does.
I saw your answer and implemented the code, but I still don't know.